# TestFlight: How to add test details to build before upload to App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I want to add "What to test" text in **Test Details** section before the build is processed and get **Testing** status. Is it possible?

Comment: as far as I know.... no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using Fastlane

It sounds like you want to start doing more sophisticated things with regards automated / CI uploads to TestFlight. I recommend trying out Fastlane which has implemented exactly what you want.

### localized_build_info

In addition to the other values you submit as part of `upload_to_testflight` you need the `localized_build_info`

```
upload_to_testflight(localized_build_info: {
                       "default": {
                         whats_new: "Your test details go here",
                       },
                       "en-US": {
                         whats_new: "Your localized test details go here",
                       }
                     })
```

Comment: where do you enter those values? Never seen that before.

Comment: @kirander You would need to use a tool called `fastlane`. It will automate your delivery to the App Store.